# niftyplayer not loading on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to share songs on facebook via niftyplayer. this is my open graph code.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE_LINK" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?= $songs['title']; ?>">
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?= $songs['description'] ?>">
    <meta property="og:type" content="video">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?= $song['name'] ?> - <?= SITE_NAME ?>">
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://<?=  S3_BUCKET; ?>/niftyplayer/niftyplayer.swf?file=<?= 'http://' . S3_BUCKET  . '/music/'. $songs['link'] . '&as=0'; ?>">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="300">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="75">
```

I used facebook debuger and everything looks OK. but it is not. it is not loading even the image or the player.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the app_id for some reason facebook does not like the app_id and i have to remove in order to make the player working. 
Thanks.